# Missing Files and Unusual Behavior

Tags: grub2, filesystem

I recently installed Ubuntu Last week 12 23 2023 on a single NVME ssd 500GB.

I was using it normally but some issues manifested:

1. I can not uninstall steam ( wound up uninstalling since no game was available that I liked.
2. I saw 10 new instances of Ubuntu under the BIOS
3. I lost files on the desktop I downloaded.
4. In the Bios when in Asus ez mode,w hen I drag up the other BIOS drived ( one of the 10) it freezes the BIOS.
5. Depending on the boot disk, It sometimes gets a grub and it says something about a shim and a grub error.

I just need the files back.

Here are relevant information in no particular order:

1. confirmed that I installed with non advanced feature, no LVM or anything fancy during installation.
2. Used Gparted to see I have 2 partitions ( which bard said were normal given installation procedure.
3. Tried to uninstall steam.
4. Logged in to Tails linux usb to see if I can access my files ( It seemed to ask for some password, which was not my tails linux and not the ubuntu password
5. changed ubuntu password.
6. tried to use baobab to search for the files ( not that I see, They were big files. usually above 300MB (around 10 folders or so with 2 text files on each folder with the 300 MB meeting recording files)

I am typing form the same computer.

[image: screenshots]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Couple notes: - Tails is a strange choice for reading files, it's designed to avoid using local storage... might work still I guess. - baobab would need `sudo` or it could easily miss a lot of stuff. Were all the partitions even mounted? - gparted works, but you can also use fdisk, sfdisk, blkid, lsblk (it shows mountpoints too) to see partitions and disk layouts. - What happened trying to remove steam, have any error messages? - Have any screenshots / photos of the BIOS / asus menus / grub problems you're talking about in the first numbered list

Comment: tails. Have setup a persistent storage. but not really primary jsut use it to browse anon.

Comment: were all partitions mounted, on the ubuntu, yes. on tails, it asks for a password that isnt my tails or ubuntu password. idk why

Comment: sudo for baobab. I will look into this. steam. i saw the same comments from steam not being able to be removed. no. there is no error messgae it jsut doesnt do anything. it is still there.

Comment: here are photos @Xen2050

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17yEf_fuwxUurblEx2E152u5aaYXbljPn photos @Xen2050

Comment: It looks like the 2nd partition of the ~500GB drive is mounted ok, and baobab can see a /home folder with 2.4GB and >30k files, browsing to there (possibly as sudo/root) should show any files that are still available. Deleted files are more tricky, tools like testdisk/photorec might find. Not sure about the booting errors, looks like the computer's own bios/efi has changed for some reason

Comment: I feel like having the multiple OS is a thing done either for system recovery automatically by ubuntu or a security breach. I just have no way to confirm. IT seems like I can not see the files. The SUDO Baobab  did not show any files. so it seems like they were deleted. I will look into testdisk/photorec. Thank you @Xen2050